# Need help with proving energy stability of forward Euler for heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, heat-equation

I have the 1D heat equation $u_t= \alpha u_{xx}$ on $x \in [0,1]$.

It has homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions.

I intend to use the forward Euler numerical scheme.
$$\frac{u^{n+1}-u^{n}}{k} = \alpha u^{n}_{xx} $$

The discrete energy of the heat equation is
$$ E^{n} = \int_0^1  (u^{n})^{2} dx $$

**Now I need to prove energy stability of the above numerical scheme, i.e.,
$$ E^{n+1} \leq E^{n} $$**

Can you please help me how to prove? I took the expression $E^{n+1}-E^{n}$ and used the original discretized equation in it but no use.